# FirebaseAuth: "The audience in ID Token does not match the expected audience" when I tried sign-in with Apple ID on Android Device

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

I'm facing this issue after I entered any Apple ID account and press "Continue" using an Android device:

> FirebaseAuthException ([firebase_auth/invalid-credential] The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [The audience in ID Token [My ServiceID] does not match the expected audience. ])

If I use an iPhone, it works successfully, the problem is after I entered any Apple ID account in the AppleId web view using any Android device.

here is my code:

```
static Future<UserCredential> signInWithApple() async {
    final appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
      scopes: [
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
      ],
      webAuthenticationOptions: WebAuthenticationOptions(
          clientId: FIREBASE_BUNDLE_ID //I have this data according to package documentation
          redirectUri: Uri.parse(
              'https://MI_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/handleAppleSignIn')),
    );

    final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider('apple.com').credential(
      idToken: appleCredential.identityToken,
      accessToken: appleCredential.authorizationCode,
    );

    final UserCredential appleUser =
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);

    return appleUser;
  }
```

Im using `sign_in_with_apple: ^4.3.0` , `firebase_core: ^2.3.0` and `firebase_auth: ^4.4.0`

I have my project registered in firebase and developer.apple.com, the Apple provider as `Sign-In provider` also `OAuth 2.0 Client IDs` registration and all the setup of the https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple package, the `intent://callback?${PARAMETERS FROM CALLBACK BODY}#Intent;package=YOUR.PACKAGE.IDENTIFIER;scheme=signinwithapple;end` I also configured the Apple ServiceId with the return URL for using `Firebase Cloud Functions`

If I use the Apple Id sign in option on any Android device, is it considered a Web method and do I need to use `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup()` as the page https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth?hl=en&authuser=0#android_1 says?

Comment: Why would you even implement Apple sign in on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

I got confused when putting the Apple OAuth client ID of the Google Cloud credentials instead of the correct Service ID of the Sign with Apple setup in dev apple page.

Comment: Can you provide more details on this? i.e. where do you get the ServiceID from?

Comment: It's amazing that I have read this answer 10 times now and I cannot understand anything of it.

Comment: @AbdalrahmanShatou a visual: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10818